# How can I perform a "swipe left" action via UI tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

How can I perform a "swipe left" action to trigger a segue and change view controller via UI tests in Xcode?

The recorded code is

```
[[[[[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar identifier:@"UIView"] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element tap];
```

but it seems that it doesn't work -- as far as I see, view controller doesn't change to the new one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly which view you are trying to swipe. The following code will perform the "swipe left" gesture on a label titled "Swipe Me". Once you target your view it should be easy to follow the same technique.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.labels[@"Swipe Me"] swipeLeft];
```

[Read more about `swipeLeft`](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIElement.html#//api/name/swipeLeft) and the accompanying gestures you can perform on elements. If you are looking for a more general "cheat sheet", I've also [got you covered](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: Yep, it works, thanks a lot. Why does my test run application several times btw? I only have stub methods `setUp` and `tearDown` and **one** UI test with the following code -- `XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app.images[@"swipeleft"] swipeLeft];
    
    XCUIElement *element = app.buttons[@"icon share"];
    [self waitForElementToAppear:element withTimeout:5];`

Comment: @Joe Masilotti Could I handle the swipe left gesture more accurate? e.g swipe left with distance?

Comment: @RyanChou you can drop down to the `XCUICoordinate` API and do a drag from one element to another. See [this example on pull-to-refresh](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-quot-pull-to-refresh-quot).

Comment: @JoeMasilotti Oh awesome. Thanks a lot. I would read this example carefully. It could satisfy my requirements.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti : your swipeLeft article link is broken. 
And how do I select which button to press on the swipe?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't `swipeLeft` on `app`

```
app.swipeLeft()
```

try calling it on the `scrollView`, like

```
app.scrollViews.element(boundBy: 0).swipeLeft()
```

Answer (score 2):

Without needing to know what UI elements are currently available on the UI stack, this has worked for me:

`app.windows.element(boundBy:0).swipeLeft()`